# Inline expansion of inline composite expression

Tags: postgresql, syntax, postgresql-11

I want something like this:

```
SELECT 1, (CASE WHEN TRUE THEN (2, 3) ELSE (4, 5) END).*;
```

...hoping to get `1 | 2 | 3`. But in PostgreSQL 11 this query throws:

> ERROR:  record type has not been registered

and without `*` it obviously returns `1 | (2,3)`.

Is this possible?

Comment: A CASE expression can only return one single value. You need two expressions when you want two columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(2, 3)` has type *record*, i.e. Postgres doesn't know which (or even how many) columns it contains. You can use the `.*` syntax only with known ("registered") types.

You could define your own tuple type and use that instead of a record:

```
CREATE TYPE tuple AS (a int, b int);
SELECT 1, (CASE WHEN TRUE THEN '(2, 3)'::tuple ELSE '(4, 5)' END).*;
SELECT 1, (CASE WHEN TRUE THEN (2, 3)::tuple ELSE (4, 5)::tuple END).*;
```

If you absolutely need to have an expression that returns records, you can cast those to `tuple`s afterwards only by going through a `text` representation:

```
SELECT 1, ((CASE WHEN TRUE THEN (2, 3) ELSE (4, 5) END)::text::TUPLE).*;
```

([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f821e821cf79efae56e9b218e97a23cf))

Comment: Why Postgres can infer column types for `SELECT 1, s.* FROM (SELECT 2, 3) AS s ;` but needs explicit type in my case?

Comment: @KonstantinPelepelin My guess would be that a `SELECT` always infers some concrete row type for the result, but I don't really know either.